# Python list comprehension sometimes slow

Tags: python, optimization

Some python code I wrote a while back came back to haunt me. It's running slow and I isolated the problem to list creation. I'm working with some pretty large lists and before I go into some major refactoring (which probably won't get done) I want to find out if there's something the experts might recommend.

**How can I improve this code's performance?**

Full ideone code: https://ideone.com/KX39t2

The code looks like this:

```
OBJECTS_NUM = 200

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    allLists = []
    for i in range(0, 500):
        starttime = currentTimeMicro()

        newlist = [Obj() for k in range(0, OBJECTS_NUM)]

        endtime = currentTimeMicro()
        elapsed = endtime - starttime
        print('Elapsed ' + str(elapsed))
        allLists.append(newlist)
```

A snippet of the output is:

```
Elapsed 242
Elapsed 280
Elapsed 286
Elapsed 292
Elapsed 301
Elapsed 295
Elapsed 287
Elapsed 236
Elapsed 303
Elapsed 282
Elapsed 278
Elapsed 902
Elapsed 8909
Elapsed 167
Elapsed 129
Elapsed 164
Elapsed 183
Elapsed 160
Elapsed 166
Elapsed 159
Elapsed 158
Elapsed 127
Elapsed 158
Elapsed 158
Elapsed 157
Elapsed 169
Elapsed 538
Elapsed 155
Elapsed 128
Elapsed 169
Elapsed 156
Elapsed 157
Elapsed 156
Elapsed 161
Elapsed 157
Elapsed 127
Elapsed 168
Elapsed 158
Elapsed 172
Elapsed 154
Elapsed 546
Elapsed 156
Elapsed 128
Elapsed 159
```

So most of the time it takes around 200-300 to create the list, but sometimes it goes up to 500 and even 8900.

I'm assuming this is some sort of memory-related behavior but I'm far from proficient in Python to pinpoint the problem.

[image]

Comment: What does `Obj() ` do?

Comment: It's true that sometimes the garbage collector in Python might run, but what do you expect from Python?

Comment: @shahkalpesh see the linked ideone snippet - creates a decent-sized object (not too small nor too large)

Comment: you know the typical thing about [example]... -- does disabling the garbage collector helps? (although it might have other problems -- however it might be the only way if you require realtime performance) -- you may also try to not allocate new objects.

Comment: @user202729 any way to verify it's the GC? (the minimal repro example is linked on ideone)

Comment: You could possibly take advantage of `__slots__` to reduce your memory footprint - not sure if it will speed things up. Or you could try `PyPy`.

Comment: Just disable it?

Comment: @user202729 tried it, doesn't help.

Comment: 0.5µs/object isn't that bad for Python; besides the IDEONE link doesn't show that bad performance deviation, so it could be something else running in the background on your computer.

Comment: @user202729 I took the output from ideone

Comment: I see that the maximum time consumption on IDEONE (with garbage collector disabled) is 277µs.

Comment: @user202729 added screenshot.

Comment: Because of ~~TIO~~ IDEONE's nature (I guess that it runs multiple programs concurrently), it's expected that sometimes programs might be slower than usual.

Comment: @user202729 I'm also testing on my PC...

Comment: I see one of the rows has a value of 'Elapsed 12389' that is 100 times more than the average loop... in another case it was Elapsed 4093..

Answer (score 2):

When measuring very small time intervals, you are exposed to interference from the system's multi-process scheduling.  Your program is never the only thing running on your system and it will be interrupted frequently to allocate time to other processes (short as they may be).  To get a better base of comparison, you would need to measure something that takes at least a few milliseconds.

To make the list creation faster, you could spread the initialization time by delaying it to the first use of each object instance in the list.  This can be achieved by creating a list class that instantiates the objects "just in time" when they are first referenced.

```
class ObjectList(list):
    def __init__(self,aClass,count):
        self.aClass = aClass
        self[:] = [None]*count
        
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if isinstance(index,slice):
            return [self[i] for i in range(len(self))[index]]
        item =  super().__getitem__(index)
        if item is None:
            self[index] = item = self.aClass()
        return item
```

usage:

```
X = ObjectList(Obj,1000)

print(X[500])      # <__main__.Obj object at 0x7fa7ac805550>
print(X[502])      # <__main__.Obj object at 0x7fa7ac805748>
print(X[499:504])
# [<__main__.Obj object at 0x7fa7aaee2da0>, 
   <__main__.Obj object at 0x7fa7ac805550>, 
   <__main__.Obj object at 0x7fa7ac864a58>, 
   <__main__.Obj object at 0x7fa7ac805748>,
   <__main__.Obj object at 0x7fa7ac864a90>]
```

performance (roughly 60x faster for this example):

```
No = 1000000

from timeit import timeit

t = timeit(lambda:[Obj() for _ in range(No)],number=1)
print("comprehension",t) # 0.886055106

t = timeit(lambda:ObjectList(Obj,No),number=1)
print("ObjectList",t)  # 0.013847651000000072
```

*Note that, if object creation order is important, this may have some undesirable side effects.*

Answer (score 0):

If it is just creation of same Obj..
then consider

replacing:

```
    newlist = [Obj() for k in range(0, OBJECTS_NUM)]
```

with:

```
newlist = [copy.deepcopy(Obj)]*OBJECTS_NUM
```

`deepcopy()` helps in creation of distinctive objects, means if we change one object it won't affect other.
With that change.

```
import time
import copy
import gc
gc.disable()
def currentTimeMicro(): return int(round(time.time() * 1000000))


x = 0


class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dummy = 0
        self.dumb = 42
        self.dumber = 'ftw'
        self.dummy1 = 0
        self.dumb1 = 42
        self.dumber1 = 'ftw'
        self.dummy2 = 0
        self.dumb2 = 42
        self.dumber2 = 'ftw'
        self.testList = [66, 55, x, 13, 31, 55, x, 13, 31, 55]
        #x += 1


OBJECTS_NUM = 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    allLists = []
    for i in range(0, 500):
        starttime = currentTimeMicro()
        #newlist = [Obj() for k in range(0, OBJECTS_NUM)]
        newlist = [copy.deepcopy(Obj)]*OBJECTS_NUM
        endtime = currentTimeMicro()
        elapsed = endtime - starttime
        print('Elapsed ' + str(elapsed))
        allLists.append(newlist)
    print(str(len(allLists)))
```

Output:

```
    Elapsed 18
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 9
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 14
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 14
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 8
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 8
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 14
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 14
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 13
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 12
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 12
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 2
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 6
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 7
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 5
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 4
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
Elapsed 3
500
```

Comment: This would create a list with a reference to the class repeated OBJECTS_NUM times.  I believe the OP is looking for distinct instances of the class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have updated the code for the same with *deepcopy* functionality.